# Downloading large files asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, download, filestream

I have a large pdf file (upto 2 GBs) on  a database server which I want to send to client for download. Also, I have size limitations on my web server and cannot store complete file on it, after requesting from data server. I am using asp.net mvc 3. Any suggestions on how can I accomplish this? Also I want it to be asynchronous since I don't want to block the user from clicking other buttons on the web page.

I have tried using this code.

```
//code for getting data from data server into inputstream
HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
HttpContext.Response.BufferOutput = false;     
try
{
   using (Stream inputStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
   {
     byte[] buffer = new byte[SegmentSize];
     int bytesRead;
     while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, SegmentSize)) > 0)
     {
        HttpContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        HttpContext.Response.Flush();
     }
    }
 }
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //some code
}
```

This downloads the file but then I don't know how to make it asynchronous? Also is there any other way to do the download that would be asynchronous too?

Comment: **[Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16348653/2007801)**

Comment: Yes, I tried this but it still takes the action as synchronous and another call to the action completes only after first one is done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX which is Asynchronous. For that use a library like JqueryUI and a plugin, take a look a this example

[http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php](http://www.plupload.com/example_jquery_ui.php)

Im sure this will do! :D

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how exactly I can use AJAX in this case? Sorry, I didn't get the example. Isn't it for uploads?

Comment: AJAX is shorthand for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML and allows you to send requests without sending the whole page. [how to use ajax]http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/ check this page on how to use AJAX

Comment: Im sorry I dont know where I got the idea that you needed to upload the file, to download asynchronously, you would still use AJAX and a Web Service. In a few minutes I will post some code that I have used to download audio files with AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Turns out in my final application I did not use web service but simple AJAX and ASPX pages this is how I got it done!

### Default.ASPX file

```
       <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CloudWF._Default"
        Culture="auto" meta:resourcekey="PageResource1" UICulture="auto" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="jsEng" runat="server">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" />
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" />
                </Scripts>
            </asp:ScriptManager>
    <input type='submit' value='Process New Records' id='trigger' onclick='BeginProcess(); return false;' />
</div>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var btnStart;

    $(function () {
        btnStart = $("#trigger").button();
        imgLoad = $("#loader").hide();
    });

    function BeginProcess() {
        btnStart.val("Collecting Data...");
        //to get the value of the radiobuttons
        //alert($('input[name=A]:checked').val()) --> [name=*] where *= whatever the name of the radioset

        // Create an iframe.
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

        // Point the iframe to the location of
        //  the long running process.
        iframe.src = "process.aspx";

        // Make the iframe invisible.
        iframe.style.display = "none";
        // Add the iframe to the DOM.  The process
        //  will begin execution at this point.
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        btnStart.val("Processing...");
        imgLoad.show();

        btnStart.button("disable");

    }

    function UpdateProgress(RecordComplete, Message, step) {
        btnStart.val("Downloaded Record " + RecordComplete + Message);
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value: step
        });

        if (step >= 100) {
            imgLoad.hide();
            btnStart.val("Download Complete!");
        }
    }

</script>
```

### Process.aspx.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;

         public partial class process : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
           WebClient wc = new WebClient();
           Dictionary<string, string> AudioURLs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Padding to circumvent IE's buffer*
            Response.Write(new string('*', 256));
            Response.Flush();

            ProcessRecords();
        }

public void ProcessRecords()
        {
            int recTotal;
            recordList = (IQueryable<Record>)(Session["UNPROCESSED"]);
            recTotal = recordList.Count();

            if (recordList.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Record record in recordList)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        curRow++;
                        step = ((decimal)curRow / (decimal)recTotal) * 100;

                        CreateDictionary();
                        CreateFolderwithAudios(record.tSessionID);
                        //record.processed = true;

                        db.SubmitChanges();

                        UpdateProgress(curRow, " of " + recTotal, step);
                    }
                    catch (Exception x)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Exception: " + x.Message);
                    }
                }
                Session["UNPROCESSED"] = null;
            }           
        }
public Dictionary<string, string> CreateDictionary()
        {
            AudioURLs.Clear();

            #region Add Values to Dictionary

            return AudioURLs;
        }
public void DownloadAudios(string _subFolder, Dictionary<string, string> _AudioSources)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in _AudioSources)
            {
                if (kvp.Value.StartsWith("http://"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        wc.DownloadFile(kvp.Value, audiosPath + "\\" + _subFolder + "\\" + kvp.Key + ".wav");
                    }
                    catch (WebException webex)
                    {
                        throw new WebException(webex.Message);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(ex.Message);

                    }
                }
            }
        }

 public void CreateFolderwithAudios(string folderName)
        {
            try
            {
                //create the folder where the audios are going to be saved
                Directory.CreateDirectory(audiosPath + folderName);

                //create and read the Dictionary that contains the URLs for the audio files
                DownloadAudios(folderName, AudioURLs);

            }
            catch (AccessViolationException ae)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ae.Message);
            }
            catch (System.Exception x)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(x.Message);
            }
        }

 protected void UpdateProgress(int PercentComplete, string Message, decimal step)
        {
            // Write out the parent script callback.
            Response.Write(String.Format(
              "<script>parent.UpdateProgress({0}, '{1}',{2});</script>",
              PercentComplete, Message, step));
            // To be sure the response isn't buffered on the server.
            Response.Flush();
        }
```

Comment: so that is how you can download a bunch of files asynchronously using AJAX, I really recommend that you read up on ASP.Net AJAX, Web Services (these two pretty much go hand in hand) and JQuery to simplify your AJAX calls. Let me know if you need more assistance

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for the code. I am using asp.net mvc 3. In that the code structure is a little different. Does that make any difference?

Comment: only in the way you present your progress to your client, you will need to figure that out on your own somehow but the Download part and processing of the file should work the same since its using C# only